# Nativescript: How to create SegmentBar in xml not programmatically?

Tags: nativescript

This is not working:

```
<SegmentedBar>
    <SegmentedBarItem title="First"></SegmentedBarItem>
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Second"></SegmentedBarItem>
</SegmentedBar>
```

I get this error message:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error in ...html caused by cannot read property
>   'newTabSpec' of undefined.

It looks like this is a system bug.

Nativescript version: 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the {N} + Angular declaration of the SegmentedBar in a non Angular application. Simply follow [this guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/segmented-bar) from the official documentation which should both code behind and XML declaration. For example like this:

```
<SegmentedBar>
  <SegmentedBar.items>
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Item 1" />
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Item 2" />
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Item 3" />
  </SegmentedBar.items>
</SegmentedBar>
```

Comment: I use {N}+Angular.
This works, but how do I display the item numbers.
`<SegmentedBar [items]="[1,2,3]"></SegmentedBar>`
Because this results in a blank buttons.

Comment: I am not sure you can when you bind an number array to the items of the SegmentedBar. The 'items' is an  Array<SegmentedBarItem> collection and you should binding to a such collection, each SegmentedBarItem has to have its 'title' set so that the button has its title as expected. You can refer the source code here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/segmented-bar/segmented-bar.d.ts#L53

Comment: Okay, it's working:
`public colorItems: Array<SegmentedBarItem> = [];

var segItem = new SegmentedBarItem();
segItem.title = title;
colorItems.push(segItem);`

View: `<SegmentedBar [items]="colorItems"></SegmentedBar>`

But no way to define only xml?